# Retrofit parse JSON into different models

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to parse JSON like below:

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "list": [
      {
        "id": 58,
        "type": "58",
        "name": "fooGroup",
        "foos": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "33",
        }
    ]
}
```

If I define models like this:

```
data class Response(val result: Int,
                    @SerializedName("list") val fooGroup: List<FooGroupResponse>)
data class FooGroupResponse(val id: Int, val type: String, val name: String,
                    @SerializedName("foos") val fooGroup: List<Foo>?)
data class Foo(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

then everything works fine.

Right now I want to take these out as a model:

```
    "id": 58,
    "type": "58",
    "name": "fooGroup",
```

That is add one more model `FooGroup` like below:

```
data class Response(val result: Int,
                        @SerializedName("list") val fooGroup:     List<FooGroupResponse>)
    data class FooGroupResponse(val fooGroup: FoolGroup,
                        @SerializedName("foos") val fooGroup: List<Foo>?)
    data class Foo(val id: Int, val name: String)
    data class FooGroup(val id: Int, val type: String, val name: String)
```

But there's no `@SerializedName` can be set for `FooGroup`, is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: You can map your `FooGroupResponse` after you have parsed to the desired class. That will be easier if you don't control the structure of the JSON.

Comment: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ use this wesite, it will create all pojos as per your response. Only you need to change array of model like if there is model[] convert it to Arraylist<Model>. Bcoz it will be much familiar with arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to restructure your `JSON`. The parser is going to make a faithful representation of the `JSON` string as a `Java` object. Your first example is the faithful representation. What you want to do is not faithful to the `JSON` received.

```
{
  "result": 0,
  "list": [
    {
      "fooGroup": {
        "id": 58,
        "type": "58",
        "name": "fooGroup"
      },
      "foos": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "33"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

BUT you can do it manually where you parse the object yourself. Here is a how to with `GSON` but it should be easily convertible if you prefer another lib.

https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/retrofit-2-define-custom-gson-converter-factory

Simply pull `"id", "type", "name"` from the `JSON` as its deserializing and make a composite data class.

```
data class FooGroup(val id: Int, val type: String, val name: String)
//You deserialize you JSON into a List of Foos
data class Foos(val foo: Foo, val fooGroup : FooGroup)
```